# Moderation on comments gone wrong

Tags: support, moderation

I don't know what the policy is on moderating comments but someone is deleting my comments in this question: [How to pass parameter to an anonymous function defined in the setTimeout call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6396121/how-to-pass-parameter-to-an-anonymous-function-defined-in-the-settimeout-call/6396161#6396161)

I believe I have already refuted both of 'Felix Kling's arguments. Someone is however deleting those and leaving the erroneously upvoted or unrelated comments.

TL;DR there is a discussion between me and Felix of:

- The use of named functions instead of closures
- The definition of a closure

Comment: How many comments from the eight currently showing are you expecting to still be there?

Comment: I think 4 or so of my comments were deleted, probably more.

Comment: Are you referring to the comments for the question, or for [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6396121/how-to-pass-parameter-to-an-anonymous-function-defined-in-the-settimeout-call/6396161#6396161)? I see 13 comments for that answer.

Comment: For the answer.

Comment: Catch me in Chat later, & I'll tell you why you were wrong... ;-)

Comment: I'd love to know why I'm wrong (which I'm not at all convinced that I am) .. especially since no one seems keen on giving any arguments. How do I find you in chat? where?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This seems like moderation on comments done right.

> there is a discussion between me and Felix

That's like your problem; comments are specifically not intended for extended discussions. There's even a feature coming out that notices when two people are having a discussion in comments and asks them to move to [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/) instead, but I think it's only active on meta right now. You guys probably got a single post to 20 comments, which automatically flags down a mod to look at it, and the mod tried to clean it up. If they left behind comments that should have also been deleted you can flag them as well, but leaving behind all the comments isn't the solution

Comment: I agree, but right now it seems only my comments have been deleted. What bugs me even more is that he is getting upvotes for erroneous statements. I will just flag the entire discussion then.

Comment: Not sure what comments would be for if not discussion.

Comment: @Lance They're for pointing out mistakes or linking to something useful; they shouldn't turn into a whole conversation

Answer (score 4):

A long comment stream should only be deleted if it gets rude or offensive.  It's especially bad to delete just some of the comments, and leave half a conversation.  Comments are intended for discussion of the answer/question and should be taken or left as a whole.

Having said that, they might have been deleted by users flagging them, in which case it takes something like 5 or 6 users to accomplish that.

Comment: +1 Totally agree. Otherwise you're just going to get a disjointed mess of a conversation.